# Probability, that a sequence of $n$ coin-flips contains $k$ changes of the lead

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

A fair coin is flipped $n$ times. What is the probability $p_k$, that the lead
between "heads" and "tails" changes exactly $k$ times ?

For example, the sequence $$HHTTTHH$$ contains two changes because "heads" leads
at the beginning, after $HHTTT$ , "tails" is in the lead and at the end, "heads"
has the lead. A tie (equal number of throws with "heads" and "tails") is not 
considered as a change of a lead.

I tried to model this situation by a random walk. Then changing the lead means
changing the sign of the value of the random variable in the process. But this
did not lead anywhere.

Comment: An upper bound for the number of changes is $\frac{n-1}{2}$, if $n$ is odd and $\frac{n-2}{2}$, if $n$ is even. This upper bound is achieved with the sequence $HTTHHTTHH...$ and the equivalent sequence $THHTTHHTT...$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in Feller's book, *Introduction to Probability Theory and its Applications*, Section III.5, *Changes of Sign*, Theorem 1.

He assumes the path length, $L$ say, is odd: if $L$ is even, the probability is the same as that for $L-1$ because there can be no change of sign on an even-numbered step. So, for path length $2n+1,$ the probability of exactly $r$ changes of sign (i.e. lead changes) he gives is:

$$\xi_{r,2n+1} = 2P(S_{2n+1} = 2r+1) = \binom{2n+1}{n+r+1}2^{-2n}.$$

Comment: Please, can you explain the reasoning of Feller (proof of Theorem 1 in page 84)? Why does he refere to -1 as new axes though he choose (1,1) as the new origin of coordinate system. And why the reflection of  (2n,2k) is equal to (2n,2k+4)?

Comment: @SargisIskandaryan #1. Feller doesn't say $-1$ is the new axis. He says: with $(1,1)$ as the new origin, the original $x$-axis, which we must cross for a change of lead, is now the level $-1$ in the new coord system.

#2. If a path from $(0,0)$ to $(2n,2k)$ touches the level $-2$, then the path segment up to that point is reflected in level $-2$. (Fig. 2, pg. 72, shows this idea.) This results in the starting point changing from $(0,0)$ to $(0,-4)$. This reflection gives us a path from $(0,-4)$ to $(2n,2k)$, which is equivalent to a path from $(0,0)$ to $(2n,2k+4)$.