# Probability that the nunber of ties in $2n$ coinflips is $k$

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

A fair coin is flipped $2n$ times. If the number of "heads" and the number of
"tails" coincide, a tie is reached.

> What is the probability $p_k$, that the number of ties occuring is exactly $k$, where $k=0,1,...,n$ ?

I tried to model this situation with a random walk. Then the number of ties
is equal to the number of "roots" of the random walk. It is easy to calculate
the probability that a tie is achieved after a specified number of steps, but
the events "a tie is reached after $2,4,6,...$ steps" are dependent.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1396281/probability-that-a-sequence-of-n-coin-flips-contains-k-changes-of-the-lead is a question related to this question. The number of ties is at least the number of lead-changes.

Comment: Section 4 in http://retro.seals.ch/cntmng?pid=ensmat-001:1957:3::62